# How to read multiple json files?

Tags: python, json, list

this is my code it's have as output 11 json files now I  need to put these files in a list beacause I need to parse them later:

```
import os
import shlex
import subprocess
#Set the environment variable
ECLIPSE_PATH ='C:/Users/AQ42770/Desktop/eclipse/plugins'
EQUINOX = ECLIPSE_PATH+'/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511- 1540.jar'
MAIN='org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main'
ORGANIC='organic.Organic'
path='C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker'

for n in range(0,11):

    path1= path+"/"+str(n)
    outversion = "C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/"+"out"+str(n)+".json"
    commande='java -jar -Xms1g -Xmx20g "%s" %s -application %s -sf "%s" -src "%s"'
    commande= commande % (EQUINOX, MAIN, ORGANIC, outversion, path1)
    args = shlex.split(commande)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args)
    list=[]
    list.append(outversion)
    print(list)
```

the problem that it return for me each output on a list I need all the output files on the same list to read  a mutliple json files
this is what it return:

```
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out0.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out1.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out2.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out3.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out4.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out5.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out6.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out7.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out8.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out9.json']
   ['C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/Android-ColorPicker/out10.json']
```

PS: the output is in outversion just need to add the 11 output in the same list

thanks in advance!

Comment: Move `list=[]` outside of the loop, You reset the list at each iteration. And change `list` to something else, `list()` is a built-in list constructor.

Comment: thanks just can u show me how to reset the list at each iteration coz I'm not familiar with python

Comment: Do _not_ reset them. And if you are not familiar with lists in Python, you should first teach yourself Python and only then attempt to do practical coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fix your code per what others are saying, to be structured like this:

```
data=[]
for n in range(0,11):
    ...
    data.append(outversion)

print(data)
```

As other have said, don't use `list` as a variable name.